# Android locMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) is always true

Tags: android, geolocation

Hi I am developing small android application in which i want to include location functionality. I want to check whether network location provider is available or not. I did this in following way:

```
locMgr = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean avail = locMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

But my avail value is always true. My device not containing any sim card and I also disable WiFi still it gives me true value. If I check it for GPS provider then it gives proper output.But for network its not giving proper output.Am I doing something wrong.

Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: i am getting exactly the same problem.